# Regex to check 3 characters only

Tags: regex

I have this regex and the rule is the user should input only 3 characters and must be in all Capital.

Here is my regex but it's not working

```
'^([A-Z\s]+){2}'
```

Can you tell me what's wrong in my formula? I only want to set a rule for 3 characters only and all must be in Uppercase.

Comment: The `{2}` does not add to the previous entity, it says how many of the previous entity.

Comment: Your proposed regex contains `\s`, which matches whitespace. Whitespace is not once mentioned in your requirements: "Only 3 characters and must be in all capital." Please be specific about how whitespace (and other non-letter characters, if necessary) should be handled, to prevent answers from being subject to different interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the original regex

- `^`: start of a line
- group

  - `[A-Z\s]`: a capital Letter or whitespaces
  - `+`: 1 or more of the previous (a capital Letter or whitespaces)
- `{2}`: There must be 2 of the previous group

This matches almost anything with 2 or more capital letters and whitespaces.

---

I think what you want are three capital letter without regard to whitespace.

`^\s*([A-Z]\s*){3}$`

From the beginning of the line, any amount of whitespace, three instances of a group, and then the end of the line.

The group must contain a single capital letter followed by any amount of whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : It should work to take 3 characters:

```
/^[A-Z]{3}/
```

Hope this is the answer you are expecting.

Comment: don't you want to add the `$` to the end? otherwise ABCD will match too

Comment: Why do you think, this should work?

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[A-Z]{3}$/
```

`{3}` is the trick to match the limit and max count.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jeffery Thomas answer, here is a working example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('fname')
var div = document.getElementById('divID');


function checkInput() {

  const regex = /^\s*([A-Z]\s*){3}$/
  div.innerHTML = "";

  let isValid = regex.test(input.value);

  if (isValid) {
    div.innerHTML = "valid";
  } else {
    div.innerHTML = "invalid";
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="checkInput()">
<div id="divID">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator says "one or more of the previous regular expression". To say exactly "three of the previous regular expression", ... say that.

```
^[A-Z\s]{3}$
```

I added the trailing `$` as well, otherwise you are only checking that there are at least three (in many regex implementations).

If you don't want to include spaces, take out the `\s`.

Comment: Note: 3 spaces match this pattern. No capitals needed.